# Flex4.6: Avoid moving to next cell in spark DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flex-spark

I 'm using an editable spark DataGrid in Flex 4.6. How can I avoid TAB or ENTER key in a cell to move to next cell?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [focus manager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/FocusManager.html) Every component has this. I dont know what you would like to do when the user hits a tab. But, look for the following methods/properties, they might help you.

```
datagrid.focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent()

showFocusIndicator
```

I think you can do  `datagrid.focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().getFocusManager().showFocusIndicator = false;`

Just a guess. But, try to get the focusManager of the DataGrid and play around with it.